# Least lossy method of texture compression in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr

I'm building a **Photo realistic GoogleVR Android application** in **Unity** and the default texture compression settings are ruining the clarity of the textures. In the build settings there are many choices for texture compression, yet each of them result in similarly blurry images.

Is there another option I am missing, or is it possible to disable compression altogether?

I'm confident that the lack of clarity is not due to my phone's resolution (my phone is a Note7), as 3D meshes render fine.

Comment: Each texture has individual compression settings. We can disable it so quality would be maximum or try different possibilities. Just play changing values to see what fits you better. Ones you know the compression you want, not sure if you can set all to that configuration with the unity options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the texture compression by selecting it (or a bunch of them) and setting it in the inspector.

Also, you should check under the Project Quality setting that the Android quality doesn't reduce the quality texture to half or quarter, that's probably what's causing your trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. The problem ended up being unrelated to compression, but the inspector did resolve it. The problem was mip maps, which was shriking the textures which were considered far away, which is problematic for a 360 photo viewer when the canvas is large.